# Fix for BREACH attack. Is this the best approach?

Tags: tls, http, javascript

One of our automated pen test tools picked up a potential BREACH attack in one of our applications. ([BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_(security_exploit)) is similar to CRIME and takes advantage of HTTP compression.)

The exploit was in a piece of JavaScript that issues a request to a .NET controller with a query string parameter that is then reflected in the page.

My fix for this was to ensure the content length of the request always varies by appending a new query string parameter 'token' with a random string of random length (1 - 10 chars). The idea behind this is that if the attacker cannot be sure if the request sizes are constant, they cannot exploit the flaw. This came back clear from the scan but I was wondering - is this the best fix?

[updated]
An attacker theoretically capture this (eg Fiddler) and modify this and bypass my security mechanism. The server does not know what value is expected, any value of any length could be passed in, the JS just randomises a string.

Comment: There are various approaches, see [Can BREACH be thwarted by simply adding a sort of "salt" into the page being compressed?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103384/can-breach-be-thwarted-by-simply-adding-a-sort-of-salt-into-the-page-being-com), [BREACH - a new attack against HTTP. What can be done?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39925/), [Current State of BREACH (GZIP SSL Attack)?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_(security_exploit)) .... Which is the best for you depends on your specific use case.

Comment: My employed method is listed on the linked post as an acceptable approach as 'Randomizing secrets per request'. Linked post provides a good list of approaches for mitigation. I've clarified the question a little.

Comment: *"...An attacker theoretically capture this.."* - if the attacker is a man in the middle and is already able to modify the  data he has no need to do BREACH because he can just read the secret from the decrypted data.

Comment: Can you disable compression? Or only enable compression for static content?

Comment: Disabling compression is definitely one way to fix the issue, from an article I read it's HP's suggested approach. It's not a welcomed approach by our infrastructure team and our applications have virtually no static content. I feel my fix has cleared the issue from the scan but hasn't actually fixed the issue, so this might be something I need to revisit with them.